# Azure DNS behind aws nginx proxy

Tags: azure, nginx, dns

I'm running a nginx load balancer on aws. One of the nodes it uses is an azure website.
So I've set up my DNS to point to the aws nginx server, and I've allowed that DNS in azure (which is a pain in the arm by the way).
Still, whenever my load balancer uses azure, I get the

> Error 404 - Web app not found.
>   1. The web app owner has registered a custom domain to point to the Microsoft
>   Azure App Service, but has not yet configured Azure to recognize it. Click
>   here to read more.

error.
nginx conf:

```
upstream load_balancer {
    server my_azure.azurewebsites.net;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://load_balancer;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong / what am I supposed to do to solve this?

Edit: perhaps I should mention that I'm using a subdomain to do this. a.my_domain.de goes to aws, I've set up azure to allow a.my_domain.de

Edit2: Problem solved. It was caused by the way nginx handles upstream URLs and the way azure handles incoming requests. Azure requires the request to be a URL request, not just by IP. nginx resolves all URLs in the upstream part and just uses their IPs later. Made a huge workaround, but now it works. Thanks anyways!

Comment: did you create the proper cname entries in the dns for this custom domain?

Comment: Yes I did. Azure disallowed setting anything before it was set correctly.

Comment: Ever find an answer on this? I'm facing this issue now...

Comment: Yes, I found a workaround. The workaround is to add a second server part with a subdomain (like azure.yourdomain) and set the proxy_pass to azure. Then, in the upstream part, enter your subdomain instead of the azure URL